# $[0,1] \ ^ { \Bbb N}$ is metrizable.

Tags: general-topology

$X=[0,1] \ ^ {\Bbb N}$, is there a metric on $X$ that induce the box topology?

I think no, I defined $A=(0,1] \ ^ {\Bbb N}$, so$\overline A=X$ , and I want to show that there is an element of $\overline A$ that there is no sequence of elements from $A$ that convergences to that element in contradiction to the fact that $X$ is metrizable (contradiction to the fact that $x \in \overline A$ iff there is a sequence $x_n \in A$ , that converges to $x$)

I thought taking $(0,1,0,1\dots$ but I see now that it is incorrect.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\mathbf{0} := (0,0,...) \in \bar{A}$, for if $U$ is a neighborhood of $\mathbf{0}$ in the box topology, there exists some neighborhood of $\mathbf{0}$ of the form $\prod_{k=1}^\infty [0,\varepsilon_k)$ fully contained in $U$. Then clearly $$\mathbf{x} = \left(\frac{\varepsilon_1}{2}, \frac{\varepsilon_2}{2},...\right) \in A \cap U.$$

Now pick any sequence $\mathbf{x}^n = (x^n_k)_{k=1}^\infty \in A$.

Noting $x^n_n > 0$ for any natural number $n$, consider the open set $U_n = [0, x_n^n)$ in the unit interval and the resultant neighborhood $U = \prod_{n=1}^\infty U_n \subset X$ of the point $\mathbf{0}$ in the box topology. Given any $n$, it cannot be that $\mathbf{x}^n \in U$. This is because the $n$-th term $x_n^n$ of the point $\mathbf{x}^n$ is not in $U_n$. Therefore, the sequence $\mathbf{x}^1,\mathbf{x}^2,...$ does not converge to $\mathbf{0}$.

Comment: Nice, I tried working with $(0,0,\dots ) $ at first, didn't worked out, thanks for the answer.

Comment: No problem, I made some changes but the answer basically is the same.

Comment: if $\overline A = X$ you could skip the explanation of why $(0,0,\dots )\in \overline A$ :-) @joeb

Comment: Yes you could. I just threw it in there anyway

Comment: The box-product topology has countable pseudo-character  but uncountable character . A metrizable space has countable character..... Good answer.